# I have an error using artifacts when I would like make a build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'm using AzureDevOps for my .netCore service but when I make the build I have a problem with versions.

This service uses a nugetFeed and my YML file is like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:


  -task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'FeedsName'
    includeNuGetOrg: false
    versioningScheme: 'off'

  -task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

I don't undertand why if I download my code and compile using VS I don't have any problem, but make this file for the build I Have this answer:

### [error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in d:\a\1\s\XXX.Services.XXX.DTO\XXX.Services.XXX.DTO.csproj

```
Unable to resolve 'System.Xml.XmlDocument (>= 4.3.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters (>= 4.3.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a task 'nuget tool installer' before your nugetcommand, otherwise nuget runs with an outdated version of nuget (4.1 per default, 4.3 or newer required for netstandard and netcore). Visual-studio already contains an uptodate version of nuget.

add the following to your yaml before your nugetcommand:

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install Nuget'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '4.x'
    checkLatest: true
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks you very much!!